# problem with threads in kotlin android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

i am trying to add data to local storage using room library in android studio.

here is some part of code

```
override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        insertBookDataToDb() // here the app crashes
}

private fun insertBookDataToDb() {
        val myApp = application as MyApplication
        val httpApiService = myApp.httpApiService //there is no problem here so not including this part i have tested it thats why

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

            val jsonRes = httpApiService.getAllBooks()     //http req here

            for (books in jsonRes) {
                val book = Book(
                    0,
                    books.title,
                    books.imageLink,
                    books.language,
                    books.link,
                    books.pages,
                    books.year,
                    getAuthId(books.author)
                )

                mBookViewModel.addBook(book)
            }

        }
    }

    private fun getAuthId(author: String): Int {
        return mAuthorViewModel.getIdByAuthName(author)
    }
```

i think the problem is when the method `getAuthId` is called it causes some problem.

the problem is when i launch my app for first time or sometimes second time it crashes and the data is incomplete in local storage but when i launch the app again(3rd time onwards) it wont crash and download the whole data.
why is this happening. any idea? help please...

some more methods if needed->

```
fun getIdByAuthName(authName: String): Int{
        return repo.getIdByName(authName)
    }

fun getIdByName(authName: String): Int{
        return authorDao.getIdByName(authName)
    }

@Query("select author_id from author_data where author_name = :authName")
    fun getIdByName(authName: String): Int
```

one more thing there are no errors in logcat.

Comment: What is the crash? Stack trace? You should be running this coroutine on `viewModelScope`. It's not interacting with UI, so the whole function and coroutine should be defined inside the ViewModel. Creating a new CoroutineScope only to launch a coroutine is an antipattern. You should either be using a scope that is managed (`lifecycleScope`, `viewModelScope`, or your own stored in a property and manually managed) or rarely, GlobalScope.

Comment: great! i used viewModelScope and made some changes here and there and everything is working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is i am calling `getAuthId()` in main thread. in my application where i create viewModel, there i had to use `viewModelScope` and it was working